# Is “The Pursuit of the Pankera” the novel Heinlein once claimed to have burned?

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, the-pursuit-of-pankera

I recall reading (I think it was in the foreword or introduction to an edition of his *Future History* collection, published after his aneurysm procedure) Heinlein's claim that he'd burned an entire novel written immediately before *The Number of the Beast* – in recognition of the fact that his mental condition was such, at the time he wrote it, that it was unsalvageable.

Now, newly released in 2020, we have *The Pursuit of the Pankera* which is claimed to be an "alternate novel of alternate worlds" – beginning exactly the way *The Number of the Beast* did, then diverging after Zach, Deety, Jake, and Hilda (and *Gay Deceiver*) made their first trip to an alternate universe.

Now, please avoid spoilers, because I'm still reading the new novel, looking forward to my first unfamiliar Heinlein fiction in almost thirty years – but is there any evidence whether the scattered notes the editors refer to having assembled to create this alternate novel, entirely in Heinlein's words, is in fact the novel he claimed to have burned?

Comment: If it's worse than the late stuff he *did* release - shudder.  (I bow to no one in my reverence for *early* Heinlein).

Comment: I don't read very fast for enjoyment -- and don't get much reading time in a day.  I'll let you know in a week or so.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm about 2/3 of the way through, and if Heinlein did try to burn this book, his brain must still not have been working right.  It's much closer to "old Heinlein" than "new Heinlein" -- I'd date the overall story style as somewhere between *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress* and *Stranger in a Strange Land*, though not very similar, in terms of plot structure, to either one.

Comment: thanks for the report! Sounds like a "check it out of the library" rather than "buy on sight" for me...at least if the libraries ever reopen...

Comment: @OrganicMarble I never had a problem with the first third -- which is preserved virtually word for word.  Unless the last third falls flat, I'm going to wish I had this on paper to put with my others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having finished *The Pursuit of the Pankera* and had a few weeks to think it over, I'm now convinced that this is *not* the novel Heinlein burned after his brain surgery (the one he claimed was damaged beyond salvage by his brain dysfunction due to his undiagnosed aneurysm).

First, based on my recollection of *The Number of the Beast*, about 40% of *Pankera* is effectively identical to *Beast* -- not word for word, but event for event.  Second, the portions that aren't the same seem to be worlds or events that were glossed over in *Beast* -- Barsoom is treated in much more detail in *Pankera*, and returned to near the conclusion; the Galactic Patrol is visited, convinced the four main characters are aware of Arisia, and enlisted to aid in the *Pursuit*.  Third, the style of the conclusion is pure vintage Heinlein, as if it had been dredged up from 1960 or before -- very *Starship Troopers*, if you will.

Bottom line, *Pankera* appears to be, as the editors and publishers claim, assembled from notes made for *Beast* but written out for one reason or another (copyright might still have been an issue in the 1970s when the book was written -- another forty years has passed, after all).  As far as I can tell, it's no worse (and in some ways, better) than *Beast*.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back!

Comment: I found the ending much more satisfying than the ending of *Beast.*  And many little things along the way I found far superior as well.

Answer (score 3):

The Patterson biography, which is a totally unreliable hagiography, doesn't seem to have anything about the process of writing the book. The Mendlesohn book says:

> In 1977...his health was becoming a worry and some people were noticing slurring in his speech. While working on 'The Number of the Beast', he gave a speech at a small convention in Utah. His performance there seems to be the source of the rumour that his later books were his 'senile' period. ...it might be better to say that they are his near-posthumous books. He completed the manuscript, but for the first time Ginny said 'no'; the book was a mess.

While in Tahiti, he had a transient ischemic attack. Mendlesohn continues:

> While recovering Heinlein sorted out the book that was to be 'The Number of the Beast' (called initially 'Panki-Barsoom'...)

Clareson and Sanders have a long discussion of the text, but nothing about the writing process AFAICT from a brief browse. Gifford seems to have nothing on the writing process.